# How to append JSON to a .json file?

Tags: python, json

I'm trying to write results in `JSON` format to a `.json` file. The file contains a JSON ARRAY.

The problem is that there are tens of thousands of such results and it's pretty inefficient to do it this way:

1. `json.load` file
2. append the result
3. `json.dump` file

Is there a way to append results to the end of the file without having to load the file?

This is my (unefficient) method:

```
def append_to_file(dct: dict, filepath: str) -> None:
    if os.path.exists(filepath):
        with open(filepath) as f:
            try:
                content = json.load(f)
            except json.JSONDecodeError:
                content = []
    else:
        content = []
    content.append(dct)
    with open(filepath, 'w') as f:
        json.dump(content, f, indent=4)
```

EDIT - this is my attempt:

```
class JsonWriter:
    def __init__(self, filepath):
        self.filepath = filepath
        with open(filepath, 'w') as f:
            f.write('[')

    def write_dict(self, dct: dict) -> None:
        jsn = json.dumps(dct)
        with open(self.filepath, 'a') as f:
            f.write(',\n')
            f.write(jsn)

    def close(self):
        with open(self.filepath, 'a') as f:
            f.write('\n')
            f.write(']')
```

Which almost works but it adds ',' after the left bracket.

```
jw = JsonWriter('/home/...')
jw.write_dict({1:1})
jw.write_dict({1:1})
jw.write_dict({1:1})
jw.write_dict({1:1})
jw.close()
```

RESULT:

```
[,
{"1": 1},
{"1": 1},
{"1": 1},
{"1": 1}
]
```

Comment: Open the file as a text file for reading and writing, seek to the end and then read characters from the end, to find where the array ends (i.e. just before the outer `]`, start writing the new elements and then rewrite the end of the array.

Comment: Do you know how to append to a file, irrespective of JSON?

Comment: @mkrieger1 appending won't do a lot of good, you need to get rid of the old end of the previous array.

Comment: @Grismar that sounds like a certain way to break the structure of the file

Comment: I was working on such function but there is a problem that JSON's ARRAY can't have comma after the last item.

Comment: I've added my attempt at the bottom of the question.

Comment: Do you actually have to append each result individually? Why not append all results at once or at least buffer some? Note that JSON isn't exactly ideal for having "tens of thousands" of items to begin with – a framed and/or binary format would be more suitable.

Comment: @DeepSpace how so? Unless the file is malformed, or doesn't in fact contain a list, it's fairly straightforward. It may break it's pretty printed-ness, but that wasn't a requirement.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at json lines, its a format that matches what you need
https://jsonlines.org/examples/

In a jsonl file, every line by itself is a valid json, that way you can just

```py
# to read
data = []
with open('my_file.jsonl') as f:
    for line in f:
        data.append(json.loads(line))

# to write a new line
with open('my_file.jsonl', 'a') as f:
    f.write(json.dumps(some_data) + '\n')
```

That way to can append items to the "array" without reading it first

Answer (score 0):

If you have no control over the json file you start with, but you know it's valid json and it only contains an array (with any content), this works:

```
import os
import json


some_data = [
    1, 2, 3, 4, 
    "one", "two", "three", 
    [1, 2, 3], 
    {1: "one", 2: "two"}, {3: "one", 4: "two"}
]


def append_to_json_arr(fn, data):
    end = ''
    was_empty = True
    with open(fn, 'r+') as f:
        f.seek(0, os.SEEK_END)
        i = f.tell()
        while i >= 0:
            f.seek(i)
            end += (ch := f.read(1))
            if ch == ']':
                j = i - 1
                while j >= 0:
                    f.seek(j)
                    ch = f.read(i)
                    if ch == '[':
                        f.seek(i)
                        break
                    elif ch.strip():
                        f.seek(i)
                        was_empty = False
                        break
                break
            i -= 1
        json_text = ','.join(json.dumps(item) for item in data)
        if not was_empty:
            json_text = ',' + json_text
        f.write(json_text)
        f.write(end)


# starting with an empty one for example
with open('test.json', 'w') as f:
    json.dump([], f)

# adding all the data at once
append_to_json_arr('test.json', some_data)

# adding the data again in lists of one item at a time
for item in some_data:
    append_to_json_arr('test.json', [item])
```

What `append_to_json_arr` does:

- find the end of the file
- read characters from it until you find the end of the array (as it's valid json, and contains an array, you should find a `]`
- then the first non-whitespace character before it is a `[` for an empty list, or anything else if the list contains something
- write the new elements over the end of the list, then rewrite the end.

For a more robust function, you may want to deal with malformed files, or perhaps with files that have json, but not a list.

Answer (score 0):

You can json-serialize your dictionaries separately, into strings, and store them in an array of strings. Then it's easy to handle just the array part of the json in plain python, you just need to write the open and close brackets, and join the json representation of your dictionaries with ", ":

```
# This will be an array of strings
data = []

while True:
    # Do whatever processing you need to do to produce dcf

    # Serialize just the dcf dictionary
    data.append(json.dumps(dcf))
    
with open('toto.json', 'w') as f:
    f.write(f'[ {", ".join(data)} ]')
```